# handle error in R and send to UI as part of response

Tags: r

we have UI screen in react which has start date and end date. we need to validate that start date should not be greater than end date in back end R side. if we have found start date is greater than the end date we want to throw error message from back end R code and display the error in UI. can any suggest how we can do this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far on a minimum reproducible example, otherwise it is very hard for us to provide help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the begining of your `renderUI`:

```
shiny::validate(
  shiny::need(input$start_date <= input$end_date, "Start date must be before end date")
)
```

The code displays the message in your ui if the condition is not valid.

Or you can permutate beginning and end date.